# Assigning static IP to GCP Cloud Run without load balancer for inbound traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-dns

Is it possible to assign a static IP to a cloud run service for inbound requests without a load balancer? I am trying to save on costs as cloud run autoscales itself so there really is no need to pay for a load balancer. I'm trying to resolve an IP pointing to a closer cloud run instance (in relation to user location) for a given domain (GeoDNS). The reason for a static IP is to benefit from GeoDNS when using Cloud DNS.

My goal:

User (EU) -> Cloud DNS -> Cloud run (EU)

User (US) -> Cloud DNS -> Cloud run (US)

Comment: 1) Your question is confusing. Edit to clarify.  2) Why do you think assigning a static IP address to Cloud Run that will help with GeoDNS with Cloud DNS? You are just changing one Google IP address for another Google IP address. 3) Docs on Cloud Run static IP:  https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip

Comment: 1) Hopefully this is clearer 2) I seem to lack some understand due to your response, but i'm trying to resolve an IP pointing to a closer cloud run instance (in relation to user location) for a given domain (GeoDNS). Is is possible to give cloud run a static inbound IP so GeoDNS works? 3) not what i need

Comment: No, you cannot change the Cloud Run ingress IP address without configuring a load balancer. You say `resolve an IP located closer to the user`. DNS does not use the service's IP address for geolocation. It uses data from the client (EDNS). The issue that I see for Cloud Run is that you cannot have more than one Cloud Run service using the same domain mapping (domain name). Therefore you can only create one entry for the DNS server geo policy for your domain and you need more than one entry. I do not know of a solution using Cloud Run.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware the client info is used for GeoDNS. Alright, thanks for your detailed answer :)) It would be nice to be able to have an IP pointing to a cloud run instance instead of a domain

Comment: Or use HTTPS Load balancer (even if you don't want) to perform that geo load balancing natively for you. I don't know how much cost a geoDNS. Load Balancer is $14 per month

Comment: Its achievable using CNAME records, the cloud run domain and region (duh). That way you can create a new CNAME record pointing to each cloud run service for each region. This eliminates the need for unnecessary load balancers!

Comment: You cannot use a CNAME to switch DNS hostnames for HTTPS. The TLS negotiation will fail. All Cloud Run generated URLs use HTTPS.

Comment: Shoot, yeah all .app domains require https. I was gonna suggest multi-domain certificates but cloud run doesn't allow you to change the cert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting @JohnHanley's comment as community wiki for the benefit of the community members that might encounter this use case in the future:

---

> You cannot change the Cloud Run ingress IP address without configuring a load balancer. DNS does not use the service's IP address for geolocation. It uses data from the client (EDNS). The issue that I see for Cloud Run is that you cannot have more than one Cloud Run service using the same domain mapping (domain name). Therefore you can only create one entry for the DNS server geo policy for your domain and you need more than one entry.
>
> You cannot use a CNAME to switch DNS hostnames for HTTPS. The TLS negotiation will fail. All Cloud Run generated URLs use HTTPS